# How to infer class generic from its function's return type

Tags: typescript, class, generics, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

How can I infer a class generic from it's own method

```js
class Controller<Body extends Record<string,any>> {
  public main(body: Body) {
    // This should have auto complete too for the body.a
    console.log({ body })
  }

  public getBody(): Body {
    return {a:'b'} //error
  }
}

// This should not need any generic parameter
const controller = new Controller()

// This should have auto complete
controller.main({a:'b'})
```

The error is

> Type '{ a: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Body'.
> '{ a: string; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'Body', but 'Body' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Record<string, any>'.(2322)

I removed some of the code. Originally it uses `zod` object for the body. Also this class should be abstract but I removed that too to make it simpler.

Comment: How do you know `{a:'b'}` is of type `Body` (since that is a generic type parameter and could be instantiated with any type, `new Controller<{ b: string }).getBody()` gives me `{a: string}` when I expect `{ b: string }`

Comment: I don't expect the Controller will be instantiated with generic param.

Comment: You seem to think that generics work differently from how they actually work.  Generic class type arguments are chosen by the *caller* of the constructor, not the *implementer* of the class.  Your question is a restaurant that has a menu but no matter what a customer orders they get a ham sandwich, and you are wondering how you can make the customer *expect* that ham sandwich before they even enter the restaurant.  It's backwards. It looks like you don't want your class to be generic at all, at least not with the information here. Does that fully address the question or am I missing something?

Comment: You are absolutely right. But for this case i want to make an abstract class for a req/res controller with zod as the validator for body, query, params, etc. Generic is the only way i think can solve it. This might sound like XY question because i think it is. I can't describe my actual problem shortly. But since it throw the same compile error i guess that this is good enough to replicate my actual problem. I'm trying @Maxime C. solution now.

Comment: If your question depends on zod you might want to tag it as such, so that people who know it can see (I am vaguely aware of what zod does but I cannot speak about whether an approach is good or bad for it.)  I'd say you don't want generics, and therefore something like @MaximeC's answer is a reasonable approach, except... it's still upside down to me. Why wouldn't you define the type `{a: string}` as `Body` to start with, and then use it everywhere like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wQjBnN)? Or, if you must derive the type from an object, something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N5adoN)?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for your help i figured it out by making the base abstract class doesn't have to know about the body type and instead use Any Record then use the actual zod type in the inherited class. While it's still a bit verbose at least it works as expected :)

Comment: So do you want @MaximeC's answer? Or should I write up one of my above suggestions as an answer?

Comment: @jcalz sure ill accept your answer if you want.

Comment: Okay I'll write up something when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in TypeScript can't be used to do what you're trying to do. Generic class type arguments are chosen by the *caller* of the constructor, not the *implementer* of the class. If `Controller` is generic in `Body`, that means calling `new Controller()` is when `Body` gets specified, not inside `getBody()`. Trying to use generics for this purpose is backwards.

Really you do not want `Controller` to be generic. If you want to try to compute the return type of `getBody()` from the implementation, you *could* use the [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) `Controller["getBody"]` to get the type of the method, and then the [`ReturnType` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype), like `ReturnType<Controller["getBody"]>`.

Bet even this is much more complicated and not a common approach. Generally speaking people just create named types to represent things they want to reuse:

```
interface Body {
  a: string;
}

class Controller {
  public main(body: Body) {
    console.log({ body })
  }

  public getBody(): Body {
    return { a: 'b' }
  }
}

const controller = new Controller()
controller.main({ a: 'b' })
```

Or, if you really need to compute the type, move that logic out of the class so you don't create a possibly circular dependency:

```
const body = { a: "b" };
type Body = typeof body;

class Controller {
  public main(body: Body) {
    console.log({ body })
  }

  public getBody(): Body {
    return body;
  }
}

const controller = new Controller()
controller.main({ a: 'b' })
```

This is the same basic type, but the `Body` type is computed.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEANFSDeBYAUEpoksCyAksAC4QBOAZiZrvvgJaU32JIBCA9gCYBPRnmb4QALiRQK1NgHMA3E2YBfXCvzwANiChQkAYV6Vqvbdpoix+GAFcARtpbwkYEGwAUDgYKl8hAEprGy0TKHMIADptXnlPDCQfISRVQM01DVExeycXJHkICgDBT0D-XxDQ6iK7amBMJEkkAHIHFtSM-HVszpwM+HCKJEHTc0tqJABeAggAdyMTWXGaMoGlswsaKPcvROa2jrSVHpVCaDguYzB7Kn4RdeAZJMqZ-akAIgcP1OVeikEMGQJWmSABQN4tBeQj+A10+kWYy2k2wvVsjmcrl2wG8vgqQSqNlGEUsMTiCWhwmOaL6XSQuUxBSKJTK+OEqNC+BqFDqDWSgj+oR6YlOvWJw1Gy2RoOA80RUomazFGxW1B2Hhx71a7VS6VEPVUQA)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need your class to be generic, you could just remove the generic part, and use the `ReturnType` utility type like so:

```
class Controller  {
  public main(body: ReturnType<Controller["getBody"]>) {
    console.log({ body })
  }

  public getBody() {
    return { a: 'b' }
  }
}
```

This will give you the autocomplete you want.

Hope it helps!